# How do I extract a JavaScript function from the following page?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to follow this tutorial

http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html

It mentions a function `inPlacePrinter`.  I cannot find the source code for this in the actual text.  I have tried poking around in view source since the interactive version seems to work but cannot locate the raw code. How do I find it?

Comment: Where is this "interactive version"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is defined in http://eloquentjavascript.net/js/chapter/oo.js.

Answer (score 2):

In oo.js there is this line:

```js
var div = __ENV.parent.DIV();
```

__ENV is not defined elsewhere, nor in any of the other js files, maybe is part of the MochiKit framework used on page.

You can replace inPlacePrinter() with this 2 functions in order to show the output in browser console:

```js
function show(x){
    var show = "";
    for (var y = 0; y < arguments.length; y++) {
        show += arguments[y];      
    }
    console.log(show);
}

function showTerrarium(terrarium){
    this.show(terrarium);

return function() {
      console.clear();
      this.showTerrarium(terrarium);
   }  
}
```

And used them in this way

```js
/*replace:*/ terrarium.onStep = partial(inPlacePrinter(), terrarium);
/*with:*/    terrarium.onStep = partial(showTerrarium(terrarium), terrarium);
```

Maybe there is a better solution, but this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like Firebug to look at the JavaScript files.

Answer (score 0):

thats a big tutorial.  About half way down the page is this statement:

But all these extra variables can get messy. Another good solution is to use a function similar to partial from chapter 6. Instead of adding arguments to a function, this one adds a this object, using the first argument to the function's apply method:

Is the function inPlacePrinter in the object called **partial** in chapter 6?